# How do I get checked input checkboxes of which name starts with a given string, using a selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I get checked input checkboxes of which name starts with a given string, using a jQuery Selector?

HTML:

```
//type checkbox
<input name="chkX01" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked" />
<input name="chkX02" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked" />
<input name="chkX03" type="checkbox" value="false" />
<input name="chkX04" type="checkbox" value="false" />
<input name="chkX05" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked" />

//type hidden
<input name="chkX01" type="hidden" value="false" />
...
```

What I tried:

```
 //This gives check boxes (Working okay)
 var checkBoxes = $('input[name^=chkX][type^=checkbox]');

 //This does NOT give checked check boxes (NOT working)
 var checkedCheckBoxes = $('input[name^=chkX][type^=checkbox][checked^=true]');
```

I need to get `chkX01`, `chkX02` and `chkX05` checkboxes into a variable.

Thanks !

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"][name^="chkX"]:checked')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
var checkedCheckboxes = $('input[name^="chkX"]:checked');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/3mJJX/)

Comment: Nice, I knew I was missing something, you are a star !